# (In)formal (and more searchable) mnemonics for standard `sed` commands?

Tags: sed

Many Linux utils have command line options with short names and functionally synonymous longer names, *e.g.* `ls -k` is also `ls --kibibytes`.  These long names make it easier to search online.  For example, a general internet search for code containing:

> *"ls -k"*

...is *less* likely to be relevant than a search for:

> *"ls --kibibytes"*

...even though the `-k` usage is *more* common, because many commands have a `-k` option, but relatively few have a `--kibibytes` option.

Similarly, some programming languages have semi-formal non-code titles or mnemonics for certain terse code strings.  For example, the name for the `>(...)` in `bash` is *"Process Substitution"*.  Searching online for:

> *'bash "Process Substition"'*

...returns fewer false hits than searching for:

> *'bash ">("'*.

`sed` code uses one-letter commands, but has no synonymous longer names.

- Are there any (in)formal names for `sed`'s many terse one-letter commands?
- Failing that, have there been any notable attempts to devise a more formal long name command list for `sed`?

---

NB: This is **not** a request for instruction about how to use `sed` commands, so the instructive portions of standard documentation and FAQs are not relevant.

Initial motivation:  An unprofitable SE search for `[sed] user:me` to find some `sed` code I'd written a few months back that used the `e` command, (not the `-e` option).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. You want to search for the options? Look them up in the manpage, it's usually quite successful. You want (in)formal names for `sed` functions? They are almost all mnemonic. like `s` is for substitute, `n` is for next...

Comment: aren't you mistaking **options** (short name with single dash or long name with double dash) with sed's **function**. In any case, `man` is your friend.

Comment: @Celada, The current command names are too vague for general internet searches.  Suppose you want to search for interesting usages of `sed`'s `a` command, general search engines won't be able to distinguish the `sed` command `a` from the English article *"a"*, ([The 6th most common English word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English)), whereas if there were a formal or widely informal usage (e.g. *"append"*) that would tend to turn up more hits.

Comment: @agc So search for `append` instead of `a` then? Problem solved? You won't find `sed` scripts that contain that command, I guess, but it's kind of infeasible to do anything about that: the `sed` language is simply built of terse commands and that's the way it is. Besides, isn't "search for interesting usages of `sed`'s `a` command" a little unusual to begin with?

Comment: @Celada, The question is not advocating altering the `sed` command language.  Some `sed` commands do not have obvious and distinctive mnemonics.

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks, not it, but closer than I got, since I didn't see that one in my search either.   Not as obvious for some, I suppose...

Comment: @Archemar, Thanks, the more distinctive terms *"options"* and  *"commands"* have been substituted where appropriate.  Please advise if still incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing *GNU* `sed`'s info file provides 33 commands:

```
# Add "substitute" mnemonic, which the info file left out.
info sed "Command and Option Index" | \
   sed -n '/\*/s/ s c/ s \(substitute\) c/;s/command[:,].*//p'
```

Output:

> - : (label)
> - = (print line number)
> - a (append text lines)
> - b (branch)
> - c (change to text lines)
> - D (delete first line)
> - d (delete)
> - e (evaluate)
> - F (File name)
> - G (appending Get)
> - g (get)
> - H (append Hold)
> - h (hold)
> - i (insert text lines)
> - L (fLow paragraphs)
> - l (list unambiguously)
> - N (append Next line)
> - n (next-line)
> - P (print first line)
> - p (print)
> - q (quit)
> - Q (silent Quit)
> - r (read file)
> - R (read line)
> - s (substitute)
> - T (test and branch if failed)
> - t (test and branch if successful)
> - v (version)
> - w (write file)
> - W (write first line)
> - x (eXchange)
> - y (transliterate)
> - z (Zap)

---

Most of *GNU*'s mnemonics seem to be in general use, but not all.  Other usages include:

> - `e` ([execute](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sed/sed_basic_commands.htm))
> - `l` ([look](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html))
> - `y` ([transform](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), [translate](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/SedChart.pdf))

Comment: I don't see how these would help with your searches... Most of them are _never_ used and the few that are used by people (like _read, write, print, change, insert, append, delete_) are generic terms so if you used them as keywords in your search you would get thousands of false positives. The only purpose I see for these short descriptions is to help people remember what each single-letter function does.

Comment: @don_crissti, It helps.  Searching the web for `sed e command`, (which mostly leads with false positives about the `sed -e` option), versus `sed e command execute evaluate`, (which immediately returns several useful hits).  The quantity of false positives is less important than the ranking here.

Comment: True but that (`evaluate`) is one of the few exceptions to the rule.